# How should Apache IoTDB save json type of data?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I was checking the datatype that can be stored in Apache IoTDB, and have a question for this. How to save json type data in IoTDB, which means the event-type data? Seems like IoTDB does not directly support storing this type, so what type do I need to tranfer these data to？

Seems like IoTDB does not directly support storing this type, so what type do I need to tranfer these data to？

Answer (score 0):

Right now, JSON data type cannot be set up separately in Apache IoTDB. It can only be converted into a string type and saved as TEXT.